# How to implement theme/template loading for an html page

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, templates

I have a web page that display a blog post list. I need a way to be able to have different themes (html structure and styling) for the page which a user can set using settings page. Once a theme is selected the whole page structure as well as styles change to the current theme. I want to implement this using Nodejs or Php.

Answer (score 1):

If I were going to try to accomplish this, here's how I would do it with PHP:

1. Store their theme preference in a database, state the changes made will be made available after they log out and log back in.
2. Whenever they log in again, set the preference as a session variable in whatever login/authenticate function you have written.
3. Create a php function that checks their theme preference and echos the corresponding css link.
4. Place the function you just made in the head of every .php file their theme should apply to (or template if using a MVC).

Just a short example:

**What the DB should have, at the least**

```
mysql> select * from _users;
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| id | _user | _pass | _theme |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
|  1 |  john | ***** | dkblue |
|  2 |  jane | ***** | redgld |
|  3 |  bill | ***** | blkwht |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
```

**Theme preference as session variable**

```
  function authenticate($username, $password) {
    # authenticate
      //
      // code to authenticate...
    # retrieve user's theme (can also be a separate function)
      $stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT _theme FROM _users WHERE _user = '$username'");
      $stmt->execute();
      $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    # establish session variables
      $_SESSION['theme'] = $results['_theme'];
      //
      // other session variable code...
  }
```

**Function to check the theme**

```
  function checkTheme($theme) {
    # remember to place function between <head> tags
    switch ($theme) {
      case 'dkblue':
        $stylesheet = '/inc/css/darkblue.css';
        break;
      case 'redgld':
        $stylesheet = '/inc/css/red-gold.css';
        break;
      case 'blkwht':
        $stylesheet = '/inc/css/black-white.css';
        break;
      default:
        # will default to this theme if no preference has been chosen
        $stylesheet = '/inc/css/default.css';
        break;
    }
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $stylesheet . '">';
  }
```

**blog.php**

```
<?=session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Blog</title>

    <?=checkTheme($_SESSION['theme']);?>
  </head>
```

Comment: Like this also looking at if the html markup structure for each theme is different.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on what else you are trying to check for?